# Has Many Through Checkboxes Not Saving Values Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've set up a has_many through relationship in my db and changed the keys because I'm working with a legacy db.

It all seems to be working but I cannot get the checkboxes to save to the database.

My models are as follows:

```
class Radcheck < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'radcheck'
  attr_accessible :attribute_name, :username, :value, :op, :groupname
  belongs_to :raduser

  has_many :radusergroup, :dependent => :destroy, :primary_key => :username, :foreign_key => :groupname
  has_many :radgroupcheck, :through => :radusergroup
end


class Radgroupcheck < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'radgroupcheck'
  has_many :radusergroup, :dependent => :destroy#, :primary_key => :groupname, :foreign_key => :username
  has_many :radcheck, :through => :radusergroup
end


class Radusergroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :radcheck, :foreign_key => 'groupname', :primary_key => 'username'
  belongs_to :radgroupcheck, :foreign_key => 'username', :primary_key => 'groupname'
end
```

In my form, I have this:

```
<% Radgroupcheck.all.each do |group| -%>
  <%= check_box_tag :groupnames, group.id, @radcheck.radgroupcheck.include?(group), :username => 'radcheck[groupname][]' -%> | <%= label_tag :groupnames, group.groupname -%>
<% end -%>
```

The form renders the checkboxes ok and I can see the groupnames but nothing happens when I hit save.

The development log is clear and I can't see anything in the mysql query log either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this in your form:

```
<% Radgroupcheck.all.each do |group| -%>
  <%= check_box_tag "radcheck[radgroupcheck_ids][]", radgroupcheck.id, @radcheck.radgroupchecks.include?(radgroupcheck), :id => "radcheck_radgroupcheck_id_#{radgroupcheck.id}" -%>
  <%= label_tag "radcheck[radgroupcheck_ids][]", radgroupcheck.name, :for => "radcheck_radgroupcheck_id_#{radgroupcheck.id}" -%>
<% end %>
```

And in your controller:

```
def create
  params[:radcheck][:radgroupcheck_ids] ||= []
  @radcheck = Radcheck.new(params[:radcheck])

  # rest of your controller logic
end
```

This is adapted from what worked for me in a Rails 3.1 project, based on http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes?view=asciicast

Comment: Still no joy - same as before :(

Comment: Has to be something to do with my naming?

Comment: Yes, naming has to be correct. Try `Radcheck.first.radgroupcheck_ids` in the console. This method should return an array of ids. And this method name is the one that should be used in the HTML form. If radgroupcheck_ids isn't a method, try `puts Radcheck.first.methods.grep(/_ids/)` in the console and look for the correct method.