# Has Many Through Alternative Primary and Foreign Keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Further to the help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278698/has-many-through-checkboxes-not-saving-values-rails3/8278930#8278930) question, I've finally got my has many through relationship working.

Unfortunately, because I'm working with a legacy db, I can't use the default rails join method and need to change both the column names and the field values therefore.

I have two models: raduser and radgroup and they're joined through radusergroup. Models below.

I can get the join to work using the keys raduser_id and radgroup_id. What I need to do is change these to username and groupname respectively.

Instead of the table looking like this:

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------+----+
| raduser_id                | radgroup_id               | priority | id |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------+----+
| 33                        | 2                         |        1 | 21 |
| 33                        | 1                         |        1 | 20 |
| 32                        | 3                         |        1 | 25 |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------+----+
```

I need it to look like this:

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------+----+
| username                  | groupname                 | priority | id |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------+----+
| jenny                     | staff                     |        1 | 21 |
| steve                     | sports                    |        1 | 20 |
| ianw                      | travel                    |        1 | 25 |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------+----+
```

I've tried the following in my models but so far, it's unsuccessful.

```
class Raduser < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :radusergroup, :dependent => :destroy, :primary_key => :groupname, :foreign_key => :username
  has_many :radgroup, :through => :radusergroup 
end

class Radusergroup < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :raduser, :foreign_key => 'groupname', :primary_key => 'username'
belongs_to :radgroup, :foreign_key => 'username', :primary_key => 'groupname'
end

class Radgroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'radgroup'
  has_many :radusergroup, :dependent => :destroy, :primary_key => :groupname, :foreign_key => :username
  has_many :raduser, :through => :radusergroup
end
```

What's the correct way to do this?

-- UPDATE --

Form code:

```
 - Radgroup.all.each do |radgroup|
    = check_box_tag "raduser[radgroup_ids][]", radgroup.id, @raduser.radgroup.include?(radgroup), :id => "raduser_radgroup_id_#{radgroup.id}"
    = radgroup.groupname
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want an id column in your join table:

```
class CreateRadusergroups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :radusergroups, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :priority
      t.string :username, :groupname
    end
  end
end
```

Here is how to setup the models:

```
class Raduser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :radusergroups, :foreign_key => :username
  has_many :radgroups, :through => :radusergroups
end

class Radgroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :radusergroups, :foreign_key => :groupname
  has_many :radusers, :through => :radusergroups
end

class Radusergroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :raduser, :foreign_key => :username
  belongs_to :radgroup, :foreign_key => :groupname
end
```

Comment: Think that works. On submitting form, it still enters the id's though. Have updated my question with form code. What do I need to change in this? J